# The temporary folder is not writable for CKFinder

Tags: php, ckeditor, ckfinder

Ckfinder 3.4.1, following error from samples:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CKSource\CKFinder\Exception\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The temporary folder is not writable for CKFinder' in /home/stroylocman/www/htdocs/ckfinder/core/connector/php/vendor/cksource/ckfinder/src/CKSource/CKFinder/Config.php:330 Stack trace: #0 /home/stroylocman/www/htdocs/ckfinder/core/connector/php/vendor/cksource/ckfinder/src/CKSource/CKFinder/Config.php(73): CKSource\CKFinder\Config->validate() #1 /home/stroylocman/www/htdocs/ckfinder/core/connector/php/vendor/cksource/ckfinder/src/CKSource/CKFinder/CKFinder.php(91): [error] 30729#0: *100469095 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'CKSource\CKFinder\Exception\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The temporary folder is not writable for CKFinder' in /home/stroylocman/www/htdocs/ckfinder/core/connector/php/vendor/cksource/ckfinder/src/CKSource/CKFinder/Config.php:330
Stack trace:
#0 /home/stroylocman/www/htdocs/ckfinder/core/connector/php/vendor/cksource/ckfinder/src/CKSource/CKFinder/Config.php(73): CKSource\CKFinder\Config->validate()
#1 /home/stroylocman/www/htdocs/ckfinder/core/connector/php/vendor/cksource/ckfinder/src/CKSource/CKFinder/CKFinder.php(91): CKSource\CKFinder\Config->__construct('/home/stroylocm...')
#2 /home/stroylocman/www/htdocs/ckfinder/core/connector/php/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php(113): CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder->CKSource\CKFinder\{closure}(Object(CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder))
#3 /home/stroylocman/www/htdocs/ckfinder/core/connector/php/vendor/cksource/ckfinder/src/CKSource/CKFinder/CKFinder.php(185): Pimple\Container->offsetGet('config')
```

Temporary folder from:

$config['tempDirectory'] = sys_get_temp_dir();

is

/tmp/stroylocman

and this folder has 777 permission.

But scripts from samples does not work. What is wrong?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with CKE 4.6.2 and CKF 3.4.1.

I was able to get it to work with CKE 4.5.6 and CKF 2.4.2.

In **/ckfinder/config.php**..

I commented out the function..

```
function CheckAuthentication()
```

And also added..

```
// This clears the Drupal error at: /admin/reports/status
// https://www.drupal.org/node/2519308#comment-10084260
require_once '../../../../../modules/ckeditor/includes/filemanager.config.php';
$config['backends'][0]['root'] = $baseDir;
$config['backends'][0]['baseUrl'] = $baseUrl;
```

under `$baseDir`.